# Erro spring - Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou seguindo este tutorial [Cocoon: Crie facilmente Forms dinâmicos no Rails](https://onebitcode.com/cocoon-nested-attributes-no-ruby-o-rails/) sobre a forms dinâmicos usando a gem cocoon, mas tentar testar o código rodando 'rails s' aparece vários erros relacionados ao spring. Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu achar uma solução? Segue abaixo os erros:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    74: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    73: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    72: from /home/kaio/Documents/Rails/Testes/users_register/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    71: from /home/kaio/Documents/Rails/Testes/users_register/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    70: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    69: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    68: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    67: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    66: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    65: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    64: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    63: from /home/kaio/Documents/Rails/Testes/users_register/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    62: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    61: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    60: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    59: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    58: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    57: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    56: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    55: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    54: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    53: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    52: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    51: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    50: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    49: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    48: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    47: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    46: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    45: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    44: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    43: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    42: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    41: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    40: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    39: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    38: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    37: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    36: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    35: from config.ru:in `new'
    34: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    33: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    32: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    31: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    30: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    29: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    28: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    27: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    26: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    25: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    24: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    23: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    22: from /home/kaio/Documents/Rails/Testes/users_register/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    21: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    20: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    19: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    18: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    17: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    15: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    14: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    13: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    12: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    11: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    10: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     9: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     8: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     7: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:81:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
     6: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
     5: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
     4: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
     3: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
     2: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
     1: from /home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cocoon-1.1.2/lib/cocoon.rb:7:in `block in <class:Engine>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Não conheço Ruby mas, as linguagens em geral, sem código é complicado dizer

Answer (score 1):

Aparece spring porque `rails s` está rodando através do spring. Mas o erro não tem nada a ver com spring.

Repare que o *traceback* está em ordem reversa, ou seja, o erro original está bem em baixo:

```
/home/kaio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cocoon-1.1.2/lib/cocoon.rb:7:in `block in <class:Engine>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Esse erro indica que você está tentando algo da forma

```
x[y] = val
```

sendo que `x` é `nil`.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela resposta. Vou dar uma olhada, mas segui o tutorial corretamente e no meu dá esse erro. Talvez seja a versão do Ruby...

Comment: Você poderia aceitar a minha resposta?